# Magento 1.6.0 API product update not working when using numerical SKU

Tags: magento

My products all use numerical SKUs, but it seems to cause a problem when using the API to do product update.

According to the [API doc](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/doc/webservices-api/api/catalog_product#catalog_product.update), you can use either product ID or SKU.

Arguments:

- mixed product - product ID or Sku
- array productData - array of attributes values
- mixed storeView - store view ID or code (optional)

But fully numerical SKUs don't seem to work. 
I'm convinced there is some code somewhere which checks if the value is numerical and assumes I must be supplying the product ID.

I also read somewhere you can pass in a 4th parameter to specify you are using sku, but that didn't work either.

```
$proxy->call($sessionId, 'product.update', array('123456', array('name'=>'Updated name1'), null, 'sku') );
```

Does anyone know how to get this working?

Comment: I had similar problems http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6748142/magento-1-5-numeric-skus-and-productidentifiertype

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer is that there's a bug somewhere preventing the last param of `product.update` from being set properly (or maybe Varien haven't yet implemented it), which also presents a problem for the method `product.info`.

A quick workaround (if you don't mind losing the option to update by ID) is just to set the `$identifierType` in the Product API `update()` method ):

In `app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Api.php` l.198

```
public function update($productId, $productData, $store = null, $identifierType = 'sku')
```

And finally load the product within the if ($idBySku) condition of the method getProduct() around l.427 of app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Helper/Product.php

```
$productId = $idBySku;
$product->load($productId);
```

It's a bit of a fudge. I'll have a look for a better workaround as an override; otherwise, maybe someone else can post a better solution.

Comment: You are a genius it works. In my scenario losing the ability to update by ID isn't an issue, since the client will always update by SKu, so this solves my problem. Thanks

Comment: Which magento version do you have? This bug had to be fixed in CE 1.6 / EE 1.11.

Comment: And it is still there in EE 1.11.0.2.. :(

Answer (score 3):

In a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6748142/magento-1-5-numeric-skus-and-productidentifiertype) [TurmDrummer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/436739/turmdrummer) posted another workaround:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/10915276/1598270

> There is a workaround for pure numeric or mixed SKU, that works quiet
>   well for me.
>
> Just add a whitespace at the end of your SKU. Magento will interpret
>   the value as a SKU, because whitespace is non numeric. Internaly
>   Magento trims the whitespace later
>
> This works perfectly from Magento 1.4.x - 1.7.

I liked this solution a bit better as a workaround because you aren't modifying any core code files, which I try to avoid.

Comment: Wishing I knew of this before I altered my code. A great alternative solution.