# Magento - How to assign product to Category by Sku?

Tags: php, api, magento, soap

I'm working on little script, that assign product in specific category based on product attributes. I have list of SKUs, but method I'm using uses that SKU number as product ID, which is completely different product. In the other words, it assign product with some ID to category, even though the param is SKU.

Example here: (SOAP V1)

```
$client->call($session, 'catalog_category.assignProduct', array('categoryId' => '305', 'product' => '10197'));
```

It assigned product with ID equals to 10197. I need to assign product with SKU equals to 10197.

Tried to follow documentation on [magentocommerce.com](http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/catalog/catalogCategory/catalog_category.assignProduct.html) and used identifierType parameter, but same result was given.

Any ideas, please?

Comment: I would use the SKU to figure out the ID of the product with the SKU in question and then pass the ID into that call.

Comment: Thanks for answer! Thats a work around solution I have used, but I wonder, if assignProduct call can use SKUs as official documentation declares. It could save me a lot of time not to get IDs first, working on large product database.

Comment: All I can imagine is that identifierType parameter needs a special value not to resort to the default of using ID, and that you did not hit that value in your attemtps. No time to look for more atm, sry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found solution!! It seems that Magento doesn't like numerical SKUs. Adding extra white space is workaround that works for me. [there it is...](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11971619/3717839)